How do I dispatch focus to SVELTE UX TextField component?
I have a <TextField/> component that I am using from Svelte UX
I assigned it an id but when I try something like document.getElementById('the-id').focus(), I get TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'focus') and it does not work.  I also tried .click()
Anyone know how this package works?  I've tried reading their docs...
Thanks in advance!

"I get an error" is probably the most common mistake when asking for help.  Just show the exact error you get.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'focus')

It means that document.getElementById() failed to find what you were looking for, returning null.  This means that the ID you expect to find is not there.  What you need to do now is inspect the HTML markup and locate the HTML markup generated by the Svelte UX component and assert if the ID is there or not, and if it is indeed the value you think it is.

Using the id should work, if you wait for the element to be mounted first.
E.g. if you immediately want to focus, wait via onMount:
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  onMount(() => {
    // DOM interaction here
  });
</script>

I generally would not recommend things like this, though, since it is easier to accidentally selecting things outside the current component.
You can get a reference to the element by binding inputEl, this also will only be available after mount.
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  let input;

  onMount(() => {
    input.focus();
  });
</script>

<TextField bind:inputEl={input} />

Another option should be to set an action via the actions property. Actions receive the element as an argument, so you can get a reference that way.
For auto focus behavior, you can also use the autofocus property, which internally adds an action that focuses.

I am using to focus after a form submission... So on mount is not the problem

If you cannot make it work with the given suggestions, supply a minimal reproduction that actually shows the issue.
